# setting the value of a UILabel dynamically

Tags: iphone, uilabel

i'm trying to build a quiz that sets the value of a UILabel dynamically through code.
i've done this successfully before, but for some reason it's not working this time. i suspect it's because the structure of this app is different. i've tried different fixes but haven't been able to get it to work.

the way my app is set up, i have a view controller with a view that has a segmented control. when you press one of the switches on the segmented control, it inserts a subview like this:

```
menuTable.hidden = YES;
additionPracticeController *additionPractice = [[additionPracticeController alloc]
                                                         initWithNibName:@"additionPractice"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    self.addPracticeController = additionPractice;
    [self.view insertSubview:additionPractice.view atIndex:0];
    [additionPractice release];
```

the view controller for that subview displays its view like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

firstNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",arc4random() % 10];
firstNumberLabel.text = firstNumberString;
secondNumberLabel.text = secondNumberString;
[super viewWillAppear:animated]}
```

my outlets are connected and i can get the values to appear by setting them statically from the nib (even though that's not what i want). i've tried to set firstNumberString equal to all sorts of values, but nothing shows up when i set the values through code.

i'd really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: Is `firstNumberString` a property? An ivar? Are you doing anything else with that string in this class?

Comment: Are you defining NSString *firstNumberString = ... ? Or is it a propoerty in your code? And firstNumberLabel. How did you synthesized it? (with or without _ or anything similar)?

Comment: firstNumberString is an NSString, and i declared the property as (nonatomic, copy), which is what i did in the app where i got it to work properly. all i'm doing is using it to set what appears in the label.

Comment: @Canopus i just used "@synthesize firstNumberLabel;"

Comment: at this point, i'm thinking that it might be because my nib's view is an instance of UIControl instead of UIView. i have it set that way because there's also a textfield that brings up a number pad, and i need to use UIControl to dismiss the number pad when the user clicks on another part of the view. could that be the problem? is it not possible to code a value for a label when the view is a UIControl?

Comment: I Edited my answer, but there is no need to make your view controller a subclass of UIControl just for the text field, not necessary just use the method in my answer.

Comment: The edited answer should dismiss the text field, but not sure if that affects the label or not.  If not then I would have to see more code to help you out

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the label connected in Interface Builder.  I would need to see more code to know exactly what you are doing wrong.  Make sure you are using a property for your label. The below code is a simple example of how this works.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *_displayMessage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *displayMessage;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize displayMessage = _displayMessage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.displayMessage.text = @"Text Changed!";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.displayMessage = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_displayMessage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Instead of making your class a subclass of UIControl just implement this method below.  When the user hits done or return the keypad will resign

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

To make the text field dismiss when the user taps outside of the text field.

Place this in ViewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                      action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Place this method within the class:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
       [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Also if you want to dismiss the text field from another button spefically and not just a screen tap.  Then just call this from within the button.

```
[your_textfield_name resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: my label is declared as a property. so that's not the problem. (i added another comment with more information above.)

Comment: i do have it coded so the user can press done, but i also want to be able to dismiss the keyboard if a user taps on another part of the view as well. it's not absolutely necessary, but it's an added convenience that i think ios users have come to expect when they have a number pad.

Comment: Check the edit.  If you follow it, you should be able to dismiss the text field not matter what you want.